# boost windows_shared_memory on linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, boost

Hi I need build one project on linux but it use "boost/interprocess/windows_shared_memory.hpp"
is any way to run it on linux, or I must rewrite this code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need to use

```
 #include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
```

instead of `boost/interprocess/windows_shared_memory.hpp`. This will handle both Windows and Linux.

Comment: More than 10 years late to the party, but... I think the direct cross-platform equivalent of `windows_shared_memory` is `shared_memory_object`, isn't it? `managed_shared_memory` adds more features on top of the plain buffer offered by `shared_memory_object`, and there's actually a `managed_windows_shared_memory` which is in turn the Windows native counterpart of the cross-platform `managed_shared_memory`.
If all this is correct, I think Mats' should be the chosen answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the windows-specific code for your Linux platform, but with a little bit of `#ifdef __WIN32__//#else//#endif` and some suitable typedef or similar to use the standard (non-windows) Shared memory architecture on Linux.

You should be able to use the regular shared memory architecture with no or minimal modification to the existing code.

Compare:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html
with (a section further down in the same page)
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.windows_shared_memory

Answer (score -1):

if you look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/interprocess/windows_shared_memory.hpp), you'll see :

```
#if !defined(BOOST_INTERPROCESS_WINDOWS)
#error "This header can only be used in Windows operating systems"
#endif
```

So, yes, you need to port it to run on linux.